# Re-use navbar component with multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple question. What is the best way to use a navbar with multiple components using react router? Just let me show the code so you can understand what I'm trying to say.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import Auth from "./website/Auth/Auth";
import SocialMedia from "./website/SocialMedia/SocialMedia";
import SingleUser from "./website/SingleUser/SingleUser";
import Search from "./website/Search/Search";
import SinglePhoto from "./website/SinglePhoto/SinglePhoto";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";

function App() {
  const logIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Auth}>
          {logIn ? <Redirect to={`/profile/${logIn.data.id}`} /> : <Auth />}
        </Route>
        <Navbar>
          <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={SingleUser} />
          <Route exact path="/socialmedia" component={SocialMedia} />
          <Route exact path="socialmedia/search" component={Search} />
          <Route exact path="socialmedia/photo/:id" component={SinglePhoto} />
        </Navbar>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So I have to reuse my `Navbar` component, and I tried to use `<Navbar />`, then the other routes below, but that wasn't working, and when I put `<Navbar> </Navbar>` that worked and the other components will appear, but is that the way I reuse my `Navbar` component?

Thanks for your time !!

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what "reuse the navbar" means to you, what the desired output should be. Are you just wanting to render the navbar only for certain routes? If you could share your `Navbar` component we well, so we may see what and how it's rendered, that could be useful information too.

Comment: I just want the navbar to appear in certain routes

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import Auth from "./website/Auth/Auth";
import SocialMedia from "./website/SocialMedia/SocialMedia";
import SingleUser from "./website/SingleUser/SingleUser";
import Search from "./website/Search/Search";
import SinglePhoto from "./website/SinglePhoto/SinglePhoto";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";

function App() {
  const logIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Auth}>
          {logIn ? <Redirect to={`/profile/${logIn.data.id}`} /> : <Auth />}
        </Route>
        <Route Component={Navbar}>
          <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={SingleUser} />
          <Route exact path="/socialmedia" component={SocialMedia} />
          <Route exact path="socialmedia/search" component={Search} />
          <Route exact path="socialmedia/photo/:id" component={SinglePhoto} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Try this!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `Navbar` to render only on certain routes then render it only on certain routes. Render the `Navbar` into a route *outside* the `Switch` and specify all the paths you want it to be rendered on in an array on the [path](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) prop.

Additional notes:

1. Within the `Switch` component, order and path specificity matter, reorder your routes to specify *more* specific paths ***before*** *less* specific paths. This allows you to not need to specify the `exact` prop for ***every*** route.
2. Don't specify both a `component` prop and render `children` on a single `Route`, see [Route render methods](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods). Just render the `Redirect` or `Auth` component as children.

Code:

```
function App() {
  const logIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route
        path={["/profile", "/socialmedia"]}
        component={Navbar}
      />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/profile/:id" component={SingleUser} />
        <Route path="socialmedia/photo/:id" component={SinglePhoto} />
        <Route path="socialmedia/search" component={Search} />
        <Route path="/socialmedia" component={SocialMedia} />
        <Route path="/">
          {logIn ? <Redirect to={`/profile/${logIn.data.id}`} /> : <Auth />}
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!

Comment: @MikeAlejandro Has an answer here helped resolve your question/issue?

Comment: Yes Drew, all of them have helped me, i made a solution by myself some hours after the post, and answer kept coming, so i read them as well, it's cool to write better code, but the answer is yes